# SonarQube redirects to wrong URL after session is expired

Tags: session, url, sonarqube

Chrome with several opened tabs is used to monitor a state of projects on a monitor,
browser extension rotates between tabs. Chrome is configured to run current tabs at startup.
From time to time browser asks to enter credentials and after that tries to re-open URLs, but doing it wrong:
Example of right URLs:
`https://my.sonar.com/overview?id=23145`
`https://my.sonar.com/component_issues?id=MyProject#resolved=false|types=BUG`
 Example of mixed URLs after:
`https://my.sonar.com/#resolved=false|types=BUG`
`https://my.sonar.com/component_issues?id=ActiveLinkOnline#resolved=false`
Looks like the URLs was mixed somehow. 
The same situation was reproduced on Firefox.
Also, the situation is reproduced if the user has logged out from SonarQube and tries to restart the browser.
If a browser was closed without user log out - all works ok.

Sonar version is LTS 5.6.6, IIS 8.5, Win2012R2

Comment: Would it be possible for you to test with SonarQube 6.6 ? Because a lot of things have changed since 5.6, one of them is that redirection was done in rails with a cookie which is no more the case